# What are ways to add a new entity to the app if the dependency controls the database structure and we can't change it?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, liquibase

**Env:** We have an application written with Spring Boot.

The application consists of 2 modules.

The *first module* is responsible for business logic and working with the database. This module uses Liquibase to control the database structure.

The *second module* depends on the first module and is responsible for the REST API (for example).

**Task:** We want to add a new JPA entity in the **second** module. The new JPA entity isn't related to business logic, it has an auxiliary function. And we can't change the source code from the first module.

**Question:** What are ways to implement this?

**Issue:** We can implement it in the usual way (Entity, Repository and etc. annotations). But how do we force the application to create a table for the new entity? In our case, it is not possible to use Hibernate to create a table for a new entity, since the dependency uses Liquibase to create the database structure. As a result, the `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto` property is `none`.

Comment: Why do you expect any special treatment? Implement with the usual Entity and Repository annotations.

Comment: @JohnWilliams You're right, but how do we force the application to create a table for the new entity?

Comment: The usual spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = create. Have you tried? What went wrong?

Comment: @JohnWilliams The issue is that the dependency uses Liquibase to create the database structure. For this reason, the `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto` property is `none`.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution to this task.

Liquibase has only one changelog file (`spring.liquibase.changeLog` property), which is the entry point for all included changeset files (such files are connected using the `include` tag).

We can override the `spring.liquibase.changeLog` property to use our own changelog file. And I should include the changelog file that was used before the property override in the new changelog file.

This way we will keep the original database structure and get the opportunity to add custom changesets.

Comment: yes that should be the right solution...however keep in mind that if you include dependency's changelog as one file in your changelog it might happen that your changes won't be applied in correct order in future (or in new instalations). But maybe you don't need this at all.